# prooftrees tree nodes on different line

Tags: forest, trees, proof-package, prooftrees

While trying to write a tableaux proof tree with `prooftrees`, I had some difficulty with putting single and branching nodes on the same line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\begin{document}

\begin{prooftree}
{
     to prove=\neg(a \vee b) \vee ((a \vee b) \vee  b)
}
[{(a \vee b) \vee ((a \vee b) \vee  b)}, just = 1
    [{\neg (a \vee b)} just = 2
        [{a,b} just = 3
        ]
    ]
    [{(a \vee b) \vee  b}
        [{a \vee b}
        ]
        [{b}
        ]
    ]
]
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to have 3. and 4. be on the same line, instead of different ones. how would I go about doing this? I'm writing with MiKTeX 2.9.6480 and TeXWorks, and typesetting with pdfLaTeX.
(also there's no tag for prooftrees, which is odd)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for posting a minimal document. I'm not quite sure what you want the tree to look like. But first thing is you're missing commas before the `just` commands.

Answer (score 1):

Version 0.7 of `prooftrees` can do this by disabling the automated movement algorithm.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\begin{document}

\begin{prooftree}
{
     to prove=\neg(a \vee b) \vee ((a \vee b) \vee  b),
     not auto move,
}
[{(a \vee b) \vee ((a \vee b) \vee  b)}, just = 1
    [{\neg (a \vee b)}, just = 2
        [{a,b}, just = 3
        ]
    ]
    [{(a \vee b) \vee  b}
        [{a \vee b}
        ]
        [{b}
        ]
    ]
]
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3 lines rather than 4]

You might want to use `single branches` in this case, also.

Comment: Version 0.7 of `prooftrees` is not yet available on CTAN. There is still version 0.6 from 2016, which trow error: `I do not know the key '/tikz/not auto move' ....`

Comment: @Zarko I've sent it. Give the CTAN people a chance to process it :).

Comment: Thank you for information. I will wait for the next upgrade of MikTeX installation (in hope that it will contain recent version of your package too).

Comment: @Zarko 0.7 is now on the CTAN page, so fingers crossed for MikTeX :).

Comment: +1 for nice answer. It works as charm!. Now I see, that 0.7 version is available more than one year ...